# How to input dictionary kwargs into matplotlib legend routine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, legend

I would like to write a function that accepts a dictionary of legend parameters before outputting a plot. I've included a small example below.

**Imports**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Data**

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 501)
y = np.sin(x)
```

**Legend Parameters**

```
legend_dict = dict(ncol=1, loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
label = 'xy data sample'
# label = None
```

**Plot**

```
if label is not None:
    plt.plot(x, y, label=label, **legend_dict)
else:
    plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This gives me the following error (which can be avoided by uncommenting `label=None`).

```
    plt.plot(x, y, label=label, **legend_dict) # this line
AttributeError: Unknown property shadow # this error
```

Why doesn't this approach work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass the legend kwargs to the plot function. Need to call `.legend()` seperately.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 501)
y = np.sin(x)

legend_dict = dict(ncol=1, loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
label = 'xy data sample'
#label = None

plt.plot(x, y, label=label) 
plt.legend(**legend_dict)
plt.show()
```

Note also do not need the if statement - label being None is fine as that is the default!

Comment: You both provided the same solution/answer less than one minute apart, but I accepted this answer (since I can only pick one) because of the note about label being None.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify the properties of the legend in a call to [`plt.legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), not in [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 501)
y = np.sin(x)

legend_dict = dict(ncol=1, loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
label = 'xy data sample'

plt.plot(x, y, label=label)
plt.legend(**legend_dict)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: When I use `label=None`, I get a plot with no legend and the following printed in my terminal screen: `UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "` rather than an empty legend.

Comment: I got that warning, as well as an empty legend. Perhaps we're using different versions of matplotlib?

Comment: Possibly. I upgraded to the most recent version a few minutes before posting this question via `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`